# Javascript library that has event listeners for music queues?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, processing.js

I'm making a graphic equalizer (for example, see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHUiXoAG2Wo&feature=related) animation using basic canvas animation. I thought it would be cool if the graphic equalizer would actually react to the music. Any libraries I can use to do this? I heard Processing.js might be good, but for those who have experience, what is the best/ easiest to implement?

Thanks.

Comment: i think this should be community wiki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the presentation "HTML5 The Wow and the How at Google I/O 2011": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WlwY6_W4VG8 
specifically see the slide 64 (00:43min or directly from http://www.htmlfivewow.com/slide64), it has an example of an equalizer, very similar to what you want to create.